# Touch area double sized on newer device

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios, objective-c

I am developing a universal puzzle game, in which I have used separate image for iPhone4 and for iPhone3, iPhone4 image is double in size of iPhone3 image. My issue is for iPhone4, touch area of image for iPhone4 image is taking double size. Suppose I have an image size for iPhone4 of `20x40` and for iPhone3 of `10x20`, the touch area for iPhone4 image is `40x80`. I don't know how it's happening I worked out in my code but I didn't get any solution of this issue. Touching is working fine in iPhone3, touching within the sprite rectangle.

Can you help me to solve this issue? Or tell me what I am forgetting to code for iPhone4 touching so that it takes touch within sprite rectangle?

Below is my code:
`

```
    -(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

    {
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
     touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
     touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
     NSLog(@"touch location x = %f , y =%f",touchLocation.x,touchLocation.y);
     CCSprite * sp= [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"1.png"];
    sp.position = ccp(touchLocation.x ,touchLocation.y);
    // [self addChild:sp z:100];
    CGRect myrec = [invisible[0] boundingBox];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(myrec, touchLocation) ) {
    NSLog(@"oneeeeeeee");
    }


     [self selectSpriteForTouch:touchLocation];      
     // return TRUE;    
   }


     - (void)panForTranslation:(CGPoint)translation
    {    
     if (selSprite) {


    CGPoint newPos = ccpAdd(selSprite.position, translation);
    selSprite.position = newPos;

      } 
   }


     - (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {   
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    Location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
     Location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:Location];
    Location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    NSLog(@"touch moved location x = %f , y =%f",Location.x,Location.y);

      //touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

   CGPoint oldTouchLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];
   oldTouchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:oldTouchLocation];
   oldTouchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:oldTouchLocation];
   CGPoint translation = ccpSub(Location, oldTouchLocation); 

   if (CGRectContainsPoint(selspriterect,Location)) {
    [self panForTranslation:translation];
   }

     if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) 
    {
    NSLog(@"respond to selector");

    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

    if (scale > 1.0) 
    {
        NSLog(@"iphone 4s");
        CGPoint mypoint = CGPointMake(80, 357);
        CGPoint mypoint1 = CGPointMake(237, 360);
        CGPoint mypoint2 = CGPointMake(79, 255);
        CGPoint mypoint3 = CGPointMake(237, 247);
        CGPoint mypoint4 = CGPointMake(78, 153);
        CGPoint mypoint5 = CGPointMake(239, 140);


        CCSprite *disablesprite=nil;
        switch (selSprite.tag) {
            case 0:
                if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[0] boundingBox] , mypoint ) ) {
                    NSLog(@"oneeeeee collided");
                    dest[0].position =  ccp(192,380);
                    // selSprite = disablesprite;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[1] boundingBox] , mypoint1 ) ) {
                    NSLog(@"two collided");
                    dest[1].position =  ccp(258,379);

                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[2] boundingBox] , mypoint2 ) ) {
                    NSLog(@"three collided");
                    dest[2].position =  ccp(173,281);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[3] boundingBox] , mypoint3 ) ) {
                    NSLog(@"four collided");
                    dest[3].position = ccp(258,281);

                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[4] boundingBox] , mypoint4 ) ) {
                    NSLog(@"five collided");
                    dest[4].position =   ccp(166,181);
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[5] boundingBox] , mypoint5 ) ) {
                    NSLog(@"six collided");
                    dest[5].position =  ccp(258,176);

                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    else {

    CGPoint mypoint = CGPointMake(106, 329);
    CGPoint mypoint1 = CGPointMake(208, 329);
    CGPoint mypoint2 = CGPointMake(97, 220);
    CGPoint mypoint3 = CGPointMake(217, 220);
    CGPoint mypoint4 = CGPointMake(92, 124);
    CGPoint mypoint5 = CGPointMake(212, 124);




    CCSprite *disablesprite=nil;
    switch (selSprite.tag) {
    case 0:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[0] boundingBox] , mypoint ) ) {
            NSLog(@"oneeeeee collided");
            dest[0].position =  ccp(125,320);
            // selSprite = disablesprite;
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[1] boundingBox] , mypoint1 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"two collided");
            dest[1].position =  ccp(200,312);

        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[2] boundingBox] , mypoint2 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"three collided");
            dest[2].position =  ccp(117,209);
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[3] boundingBox] , mypoint3 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"four collided");
            dest[3].position =  ccp(200,208);

        }
        break;
    case 4:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[4] boundingBox] , mypoint4 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"five collided");
            dest[4].position =  ccp(113,127);
        }
        break;
    case 5:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[5] boundingBox] , mypoint5 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"six collided");
            dest[5].position =  ccp(207,126);

        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
    }
      }

   } 


    -(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
      CGPoint mypoint = CGPointMake(106, 329);
      CGPoint mypoint1 = CGPointMake(208, 329);
      CGPoint mypoint2 = CGPointMake(97, 220);
       CGPoint mypoint3 = CGPointMake(217, 220);
     CGPoint mypoint4 = CGPointMake(92, 124);
     CGPoint mypoint5 = CGPointMake(212, 124);
     switch (selSprite.tag) {
      case 0:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[0] boundingBox] , mypoint ) ) {
            NSLog(@"oneeeeee collided");
            if (corsprite == TRUE) {
                correctplace++;
                corsprite = FALSE;
            }
        }else {
            selSprite.position = ccp(110,50);
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[1] boundingBox] , mypoint1 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"two collided");
            if (corsprite2 == TRUE) {
                correctplace++;
                corsprite2 = FALSE;
            }
        }else {
            selSprite.position = ccp(110, 65);
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[2] boundingBox] , mypoint2 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"three collided");
            if (corsprite3 == TRUE) {
                correctplace++;
                corsprite3 = FALSE;
            }
        }else {
            selSprite.position =ccp(130, 10);
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[3] boundingBox] , mypoint3 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"four collided");
            if (corsprite4 == TRUE) {
                correctplace++;
                corsprite4 = FALSE;
            }
        }else {
            selSprite.position = ccp(215, 10);
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[4] boundingBox] , mypoint4 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"five collided");
            if (corsprite5 == TRUE) {
                correctplace++;
                corsprite5 = FALSE;
            }
        }else {
            selSprite.position = ccp(220,70);
        }
        break;
    case 5:
        if (CGRectContainsPoint( [dest[5] boundingBox] , mypoint5 ) ) {
            NSLog(@"six collided");
            if (corsprite6 == TRUE) {
                correctplace++;
                corsprite6 = FALSE;
            }           
        }else {
            selSprite.position = ccp(220,70);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
   }
```

`

Comment: touching area is double of iphone4 image but touch area is same as iphone3 image.

Comment: It may help if you included a small amount of code, just the part where you're creating the images and where you're detecting the touch.

Comment: Did you even read my answer before adding the code to your question? How/Where do you define your rectangle (I guess that would be `invisible[0]`)? Also this code is a huge mess... you really **don't** need to do everything twice (once for iPhone 4 and once for older devices).

Answer (score 5):

On iOS there are two different units of measurement. *Points* and *Pixels*. On older devices a point is equal to a pixel. On new devices, there are two pixels for each point, both vertically and horizontally (so totally 4 pixels per point). An iPhone 3 has `480x320` pixels and `480x320` points. Whereas an iPhone 4 has `960x640` pixels and `480x320` points! The important bit here is that the number of points remain the same for old and new devices.

So I'm assuming you're working with pixel sizes instead of point sizes here. When you define a rectangle to be `20x40` on a new device, then this is in points, **not** pixels. Which in turn results in a `40x80` pixel rectangle, which is of course double the size of your image. Your image of size `20x40` is actually `10x20` points in size (on an iPhone 4).

I don't know how you retrieve your rectangle sizes. If they are hard-coded, just always use the one for the low-res device. If you're measuring them at runtime, always use methods like `contentSize` instead of `contentSizeInPixels`.

**Summary**: Work with points instead of pixels, as points remain the same across iPhone 1 - 4.

Comment: I am using point as you can see my code, and here i am scaling my images so i have defined twice, one for iphone3 and second for iphone4. i checked my code i have not use pixel.

Comment: @Anilgupta I'm pretty sure the issue is because of using incorrect sizes. Without seeing the full source it's impossible to tell though. Did you name your HD assets with the suffix `-hd.png`? Also why do you have different code/coordinates for iPhone4 (see `if (scale > 1.0)` in your code)?

Comment: yes i have name the image with suffix -hd.png for iphone4 and with out suffix -hd.png for iphone3, can you give me your skype or any IM id so that i can share my screen with you , i am struggling with this issue, i will be very thankful to you.

Comment: you didnt reply me, please help me .. can you tell me, how i can get which device is using like iphone4 or iphone3 any other code to know which device is using so that i can change my code.

Comment: @Anilgupta I'm sorry, but I can't help you via IM. You could either take this to the chat or the [cocos2d forums](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/). And I say it again: You **do not** have to detect iPhone 4 or 3. They have the same resolution in points. As long as you use points, there's no need for different coordinates! Throw all your iPhone 4 specific code away and use only the iPhone 3 coordinates.